# Phonon branch-resolved harmonic sampling

Tags: phonons, phonopy

I would like to do a phonon band-resolved harmonic sampling, following the recipes from the paper by West and Estreicher ([harmonic sampling](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.96.115504)). In fact, the method presented in the paper is already implemented in some codes devoted to the lattice dynamics (TDEP, fhi-vibes) at finite temperature.

The methodology is described in details in [TDEP manual](https://ollehellman.github.io/program/canonical_configuration.html). Thus, I would just point to the equations (2)-(6) in the mentioned manual.

In this approach eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the dynamical matrix computed at the Gamma-point are used. In other words, we got data from the commensurate q-points.

In my case, I would like to do displacements using particular phonon branch. Which means that I should take only those eigenvectors and eigenstates of the dynamical matrix, which are related to the same phonon branch. Consequently, is there anyone who knows a method to assign phonon branch label to the specific eigenvector, eigenvalue? Any hints on how to do that are highly appreciated.

Since I already spend some time trying to figure it out on my own I would share what I have found at the moment. First of all, I looked if phonopy has anything related to this problem. It turned out that in phonopy during the plotting of the phonon dispersion there is a function, which estimates which q-points to connect (estimate_band_connection in the [phonopy/phonon](https://github.com/phonopy/phonopy/blob/develop/phonopy/phonon/band_structure.py))  and it works simply based on the scalar product between different eigenvectors at neighboring qpoints. I am not sure that this method is completely reliable, i.e. what do to with band-crossing (use symmetry representation of phonons of this branches?). In addition to that I have found out this paper ([How to resolve a phonon-associated property into
contributions of basic phonon modes](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2515-7639/ab2b7c)), but this methodology seems to be similar to the one used in Phonopy and I am also not sure if this is what I need.

Sincerely,
Nikita Rybin PhD student at the FHI, Berlin

Comment: +1 Welcome to our site!

Comment: +1 and welcome again to our community! Have you figured out anything more about this over the last 6+ months? Please update us!

Comment: Hello! Perhaps, the most general formalism, which would allow to perform such analysis is based on the Berry phase theory. There are a bunch of papers doing this, for example, https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.101.081403, and https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-21293-2. Authors of the latter paper wrote that the code they developed can be shared. I haven't tried it, since in my case the link to the paper I mentioned in the text of the question worked.

Comment: @NikitaRybin nice. It looks like you've figured things out? Can you write a self-answer? It would be very helpful for future users that visit the site!

Answer (score 1):

OP:

> "Hello! Perhaps, the most general formalism, which would allow to perform such analysis is based on the Berry phase theory. There are a bunch of papers doing this, for example, journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.101.081403, and nature.com/articles/s41467-021-21293-2. Authors of the latter paper wrote that the code they developed can be shared. I haven't tried it, since in my case the link to the paper I mentioned in the text of the question worked."